# How to fit dates on a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following dataframe, which I am trying to plot.

```
    Date    Light (umols)   Time_difference Time_analysis
0   2018-11-17 00:00:00 5000.0  0 days 00:00:00 fine
1   2018-11-17 00:03:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
2   2018-11-17 00:06:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
3   2018-11-17 00:09:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
4   2018-11-17 00:12:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine

... ... ... ... ...
482785  2021-02-22 23:59:56 634.4   0 days 00:00:00 fine
482786  2021-02-22 23:59:57 574.3   0 days 00:00:00 fine
482787  2021-02-22 23:59:58 598.9   0 days 00:00:00 fine
482788  2021-02-22 23:59:59 676.9   0 days 00:00:00 fine
482789  2021-02-23 00:00:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
```

As you can see it is gigantic, so I am resorting to breaking it down into about 10 smaller df's.

I am wanting to plot the 'Date' and 'Light (umols)' columns as a continuous plot on a line graph.

Unfortunately, when I try the code below, the datetimes that I want to plot are all squished and illegible.

```
ax = plt.gca()

closer_1.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'Date', y = 'Light (umols)', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

closer_1 produces the following:

```
    Date    Light (umols)   Time_difference Time_analysis
0   2018-11-17 00:00:00 5000.0  0 days 00:00:00 fine
1   2018-11-17 00:03:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
2   2018-11-17 00:06:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
3   2018-11-17 00:09:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
4   2018-11-17 00:12:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
... ... ... ... ...
25675   2018-12-31 23:45:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
25676   2018-12-31 23:48:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
25677   2018-12-31 23:51:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
25678   2018-12-31 23:54:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
25679   2018-12-31 23:57:00 5000.0  0 days 00:03:00 fine
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the output of `print(closer_1.Date.dtype)`?

Comment: As a follow up, my colleague tried to alter the size, and this resulted in the dates completely disappearing, and I want all the dates from closer_1 to be shown clearly, one by one.

Comment: @tdy The output is 'object'